# How can I get the delegate?

Tags: cocoa, macos, delegates

In iOS to get the delegate I use following code:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

How to get the delegate in Cocoa Mac programming?

Answer (score 29):

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate];
```

see the docs for [NSApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSApp) for more info.

Comment: Note that `NSApp` is really just the same thing as `[NSApplication sharedApplication]`

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 5

```
let delegate = (NSApplication.shared.delegate) as! AppDelegate
```